# Swift: Overload or route to a generic method based on possibility of protocol conformance?

Tags: swift, generics, methods, overloading, swift-protocols

In a generic processing chain, I've got a method which processes a result. I want to process differently if the generic Type happens to conform to a protocol.

I wanted to overload the method based on protocol conformance. This method of switching gets past the compiler (where if switching based on protocol conformance does not).

Unfortunately the compiler never uses the more specific overload when it's called from a method in the processing chain which isn't already typed for that protocol. Is this not currently possible?

Here's an example:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    var protocolString: String { get }
}

struct SpecialResult: MyProtocol {
    let protocolString: String = "special MyProtocol"
}

func preProcess<T>(result: T) {
    // Process chain for any kind of T
    print("PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: \(T.self is MyProtocol.Type)") // always prints true
    process(result: result)
}

func process<T>(result: T) where T: MyProtocol { // Doesn't matter if I use process<T: MyProtocol>
    // process specifically for MyProtocol
    print("I'm processing a \(result.protocolString) result!")
}

func process<T>(result: T) {
    // process generically for T
    print("I'm processing a result.")
    print("Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: \(T.self is MyProtocol.Type)") // always prints true
}

let result = SpecialResult()
preProcess(result: result)
process(result: result)

// PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
// I'm processing a result.
// Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
// I'm processing a special MyProtocol result!
```

I'd expect it to print the special MyProtocol line twice.

Any solutions for this? Even without the method overloading, I can't seem to get the routing to work.

I can skip overloading and use two different method names, calling each behind an `if T.self is MyProtocol.Type`, but the compiler still complains that the true case needs to conform to MyProtocol, which it obviously must if it's in the true case!

I can cast the `result as? MyProtocol`, but then I lose its underlying type, which I need throughout the processing chain. I really need a way to do something like `result as? T: MyProtocol`, but I can't seem to find a way how...

Comment: I think you are imagining a hierarchy, or a use of overloading, that doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you mean? The overloading routs to the correct method when outside the generic chain. Outside `preProcess` the `result` can obviously be any type, and it works. Inside `preProcess` the `result` can also be any type, but it doesn't work.

Comment: No, it's not doing any dynamic routing outside the generic chain. It all happens at compile time. You say `let result = SpecialResult()` so the compiler knows what this thing is. So when you say `process` you get the one for MyProtocol. In general, though, the idea of using `where` clauses to do some sort of overload-and-dispatch is a mistaken goal; that's not how Swift works. The very use of the word "overload" in the question shows the issue.

Comment: I don't see how this is fundamentally different that the compiler knows the type of `result` when passing it into `process<T>(result: T)` but not when you pass it into `preProcess<T>(result: T) { process<T>(result: T) }`. I mean it works that way for Types, but just not Protocoled types. I get that it *doesn't* do that currently. But it doesn't seem to be for the reasons you state (which work fine when not using Protocols with your generics).

Comment: @matt As for the overloading being the wrong approach. It's about the 10th approach I've tried to process a generic type T slightly differently if T: MyProtocol, without collapsing the object into just a MyProtocol, and losing its inherent T-ness.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you're saying that protocols are in some way not full-fledged types, and that is definitely true.

Comment: It would probably help here if you explained what "without collapsing the object into just a MyProtocol, and losing its inherent T-ness" means. What difference in output are you trying to get by maintaining the "inherent T-ness?" (I suspect the problem here is that you're using `print` as your example, and `print` always makes a bad example because it accepts Any, and tends to always work for everything, which isn't true for most use cases.)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few mistakes here. The most basic is this construct:

```
T.self is MyProtocol.Type
```

That's just wrong. What you mean is:

```
result is MyProtocol
```

Or you could use:

```
T.self is MyProtocol
```

(but you should probably use the `result` version)

The thing you're using is roughly "T is a subtype *of the type* of MyProtocol" which means "T is a metatype" which really isn't what you mean (and in fact, I'm not really sure it means anything useful).

So that gives you:

```
func preProcess<T>(result: T) {
    // Process chain for any kind of T
    print("PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: \(result is MyProtocol)") // always prints true
    process(result: result)
}
```

Since you want to do runtime consideration of types, you need to use runtime checks (i.e. "if" statements, not generics). I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to get out of this, but I expect it's along these lines:

```
func process<T>(result: T) {
    let resultType: String
    if let myProtocol = result as? MyProtocol {
        resultType = myProtocol.protocolString
    } else {
        resultType = ""
    }

    print("I'm processing a \(resultType) result.")
    print("Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: \(result is MyProtocol)")
}
```

Together, that gives:

```
PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
I'm processing a special MyProtocol result.
Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
I'm processing a special MyProtocol result.
Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
```

Which is what I think you mean. Of course you could rewrite the big `if` statement with a crammed-together `??`:

```
let resultType = (result as? MyProtocol)?.protocolString ?? ""
```

Or you could split out your processing in the `if` rather than using string values, or whatever.

You could also write it this way (which may be what you mean):

```
func process(result: MyProtocol) {
    print("I'm processing a \(result.protocolString) result!")
}

func process<T>(result: T) {
    // process generically for T
    if let result = result as? MyProtocol {
        process(result: result)
    } else {
        print("I'm processing a result.")
    }
}
```

I tend to be a little careful about overloading with the same name like this, where it might be ambiguous (I'd probably name the first one `process(myProtocol:)`). It totally works, and can be very useful (see the various `encode` methods in the Encoder containers in stdlib). But it can also be a bit confusing, so it should be used with great care.

But the most important take-away is in matt's answer. Generics are not dynamic dispatch. They are determined 100% at compile-time, based on compile-time information. As a rule, generic overloads should only ever be used to improve performance (supporting better algorithms for BidirectionalCollections than just Collections). They shouldn't be used to change behavior. That path rarely works the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer, upvoted. Unfortunately the if conditional doesn't work (though it can in my simplified example). When I do `if let result = result as? MyProtocol`, I lose the *actual* type of result, which I need to retain throughout the processing chain. What I really need is a way to cast `result as? T: MyProtocol`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that? Or any way to switch while retaining the generic T?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you plan to do with the "actual type of result" here, but it's not lost. It's available as `type(of: result)`. Maybe I'm not clear on what you mean by the "processing chain?" Can you show what you want to call, and what you want the output to be?

Comment: As an example of keeping the original type, change `process` to `print("I'm processing a \(result.protocolString) result, of type: \(type(of: result))!")`, and it'll print that's a SpecialResult, even the compiletime type is MyProtocol. But to be clear: generics *cannot* do dynamic dispatch. So if you're trying to fake your way to that, it's not going to work. You need another tool than generics (generally protocols, but also `as?` casting).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think some sort of dynamic dispatch is going to happen here. It isn't. That is not what a generic is.

A generic is resolved at compile time. The runtime is not going to override the compiler's behavior based on a real-time examination of the parameter. All the compiler knows in `preProcess` is that this thing is a T, which could be of any type. So it picks the general implementation.

If *you* want to check, in code, for what sort of thing this is, and downcast to tell the compiler that, fine, you can do that. But the runtime is not going to do that for you.

Comment: How would you do the routing then? I can skip overloading and use two different method names, calling each behind a `if T.self is MyProtocol.Type`, but the compiler still complains that the true case needs to conform to MyProtocol, which it obviously must. I can cast the result as? a MyProtocol, but then I lose its underlying type...

Comment: Also, the compiler obviously looks into the `result` constant for its type when called outside the `preProcess` method and properly routs it to the correct `process` method. So I'm confused why it couldn't do the same look into `result` and remember its type through `preProcess`.

Comment: @RobNapier That loses the underlying type that's been passed through the optional chain though. What I really need is to cast it as T: MyProtocol. But I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: I'm working on an answer, but it's very unclear what you're trying to do here. There are several definite mistakes, but your actual goal is murky. (matt is 100% correct; I'm just working on code that might be what you mean)

Answer (score 0):

When you write :

```
let result = SpecialResult()
preProcess(result: result)
```

the compiler knows the type of `result` but in `func preProcess<T>(result:)` `T` could be **any**thing so it will always call the unspecialized version `process<T>(result:)`.

One way to help the compiler retain the type information would be to add a `Processor` protocol:

```
protocol Processor {
    associatedtype T
    func description(for result: T) -> String
}

extension Processor {
    func preProcess(result: T) {
        // Process chain for any kind of T
        print("PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: \(T.self is MyProtocol.Type)") // always prints true
        process(result: result)
    }

    func process(result: T) {
        // process generically for T
        print("I'm processing a \(description(for: result)).")
        print("Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: \(result is MyProtocol)") // always prints true
    }
}
```

The idea is to let conforming types worry about handling the results, here it is only the description but it can be anything really.

now there's two options:

- a generic class for all the possible results:

```
struct ResultProcessor<T>: Processor {
    let result: T
    
    func description(for result: T) -> String {
        if let myProtocol = result as? MyProtocol {
            return myProtocol.protocolString
        } else {
            return "result"
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let result = SpecialResult()
let processor = ResultProcessor(result: result)
processor.preProcess(result: result)
processor.process(result: result)

// PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
// I'm processing a special MyProtocol.
// Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
// I'm processing a special MyProtocol.
// Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
```

Or a specialized classes for each known type of results :

```
struct SpecialResultProcessor: Processor {
    let result: SpecialResult
    
    func description(for result: SpecialResult) -> String {
        "special \(result.protocolString) result"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let specialResultProcessor = ResultProcessor(result: result)
specialResultProcessor.preProcess(result: result)
specialResultProcessor.process(result: result)

// PreProcess: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
// I'm processing a special MyProtocol.
// Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
// I'm processing a special MyProtocol.
// Process: T conforms to MyProtocol: true
```